# Case Select statement not firing macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a private sub macro within a tab called "Model" that I'm hoping will hide and unhide sheets and columns based on a concatenated formula value in cell O1 of the model tab.  However, when I make a change on the worksheet, the macro doesn't appear to do what I'd like it to.  Below is my code, and I'd really appreciate any assistance anyone can provide.  I'm pretty novice when it comes to VBA.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

Worksheets("Model").Range("O1").Calculate
Dim test As String
test = Worksheets("Model").Range("O1").Value
Select Case test
    Case "", "new", "credit", "Non-Credit", "Existing"
        Exit Sub
    Case "Non-CreditNew"
        Sheets("Enrollment Waterfall-Credit-New").Visible = False
        Sheets("Enrollment Waterfall-New").Visible = True
        Sheets("Enrollment Waterfall-Credit-Exs").Visible = False
        Columns("Z:AR").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("AT:BH").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("F:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Case "Non-CreditExisting"
        Sheets("Enrollment Waterfall-Credit-New").Visible = False
        Sheets("Enrollment Waterfall-New").Visible = True
        Sheets("Enrollment Waterfall-Credit-Exs").Visible = False
        Columns("Z:AR").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("AT:BH").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("F:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Case "CreditNew"
        Columns("F:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Sheets("Enrollment Waterfall-Credit-New").Visible = True
        Sheets("Enrollment Waterfall-New").Visible = False
        Sheets("Enrollment Waterfall-Credit-Exs").Visible = False
        Columns("Z:AR").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("AT:BH").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Case "CreditExisting"
        Sheets("Enrollment Waterfall-Credit-New").Visible = False
        Sheets("Enrollment Waterfall-New").Visible = False
        Sheets("Enrollment Waterfall-Credit-Exs").Visible = True
        Columns("Z:AR").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("AT:BH").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("F:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Drop the `test = ` from each of the `Case` lines...

Comment: ^^^ or change the `Select Case test` to `Select Case True`

Comment: Neither one of these worked to hide or unhide the columns and/or sheets. Am I missing something else?

Comment: What "change" are you making? Seems like the `Worksheet_Calculate` event might be more appropriate (?)

Comment: @BigBen--I have a data entry table where people enter information.  I only want to macro to fire when people have completed entering the information, so I made "lookup" cell in O1 that concatenates the necessary values in the data entry fields.  If the values in O1 meet certain criteria, I want the macro to fire off and hide/unhide columns and pages.  I have this as a change event because I don't want it to fire off every time a calculation occurs on this tab.  It's mostly formula driven with little data entry except for the table.

Comment: @BigBen--I'm happy to upload my file if you'd like to see it.  Like I said, I'm pretty novice at VBA so the code is most likely incredibly inelegant.

Comment: @AubreyDubberke 1.) Change `Dim test As Variant` to `Dim test As String`  2.) Remove `test = ` from all your case statements

Comment: @jblack--I've updated the code to the above.  Still not hiding and unhiding.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: @AubreyDubberke You've changed your case statements. They should be as they previously were, only, instead of writing `Case test = "new"` you should just say `Case "new"`. Apply that same format to all your case statements and it will work

Comment: @jblack...still not working...Is there anyway to upload the file on here for you to see it for yourself? If you're interested in doing that.

Comment: @jblack--I made your changes.  Still nothing.  Could something be broken in the file?  I'm stumped.

Comment: @jblack--nevermind.  Classic IT problem.  I had to shut my computer off and turn it back on again.  Once I did that, it worked.  Thanks so much for your help and patience!

Comment: @AubreyDubberke glad it helped :)